# Compile stack script instead of running it

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

The build tool `stack` has the feature to treat a usually compiled haskell source file as a script. (https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter)

Is it also possible to create a compiled executable the same way?

I searched the `help` section of `stack` and `stack script`, but could not find an options that make this possible.

script.hs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{-
  stack script
  --resolver lts-13.14
  --package turtle
-}

main = print "hello"
```

So if given it the right permissions, this file can be executed. I guess  behind the scenes stack compiles the file and then just runs it. And I'd like to just get the compiled intermediate binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not compiled. It's run through `runhaskell` which is a Haskell interpreter. If you want to compile it... do that. Instead of running the script,
take the `--resolver` and `--package` options from the script comment and pass them like this

```sh
stack ghc --resolver lts-13.14 --package turtle test.hs
```

Comment: New answer added :)

Answer (score 0):

The `script` command takes both `--compile` and `--optimize` as flags, which will instruct Stack to first compile to an executable (optionally with `-O2` optimization level) before running.

Comment: Tried 
`#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack script --resolver lts-16.26 --compile
main = print "hello"
`
got
`run_serv.sh:2:1: syntax error, unexpected '-', expecting $end`. Stack version 2.5.1