# How to compile a haskell/stack script into an executable?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

This question is similar to [Compile stack script instead of running it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501455/compile-stack-script-instead-of-running-it) but I don't think it has been answered completely.

I have a script which I want to run in two ways:

1. Using `./Script.hs` when I am developing it locally, and need a fast develop-run-test cycle
2. Compiling it to a standalone binary (static, if possible), so that I can ship it to my production servers without any dependency on haskell/stack.

I've tried putting the following on top of my script, but that results in the following error `Did not find executable at specified path: <the path of my script>`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
   --resolver=lts-15.6
   script
   --compile
   --copy-bins
   --package shake
   --package bytestring
   --package text
   --package hashable
   --package binary
   --package deepseq
   --package string-conv
   --package http-client
   --package http-types
   --package safe
   --ghc-options=-threaded
   --ghc-options=-with-rtsopts=-N
-}
```

Comment: if you are looking for fast develop/run cycles why not use GHCi or [ghcid](https://github.com/ndmitchell/ghcid#evaluation)  - you can have the last one constantly evaluate/test stuff very similar to what your script does I think?

Comment: I was having the same issue and it was because of a module declaration in my file. Commenting that out allowed it to create the executable.